# Act as list with self-referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a self-referential association for categories table:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories,
           class_name: 'Category',
           foreign_key: 'parent_id',
           dependent: :destroy,
           inverse_of: :parent
  belongs_to :parent,
             class_name: 'Category',
             optional: true,
             inverse_of: :subcategories
end
```

I wanted to add `act_as_list` gem to manage position of elements for main categories and subcategories in scope of main category. As I read documentation it seems that there is no possibility for such scenario. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I would recommend you to find another gem for this. The Github repo is archived, it hasn't been updated since 2009 and the documentation is pretty poor. There must be better gems for that kind of job (like this one https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree)

Comment: Are you sure? Last update was 12days ago - https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Comment: Oh! I was looking at the wrong one (rails/acts_as_list), my bad

Comment: if there are subcategories of categories... it's a tree, though, not a list - so I'd still recommend looking at something like `acts_as_tree` ;)